# Bluetooth connection timeout: dm_pm_timer expires

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm facing a problem where the bluetooth connection times out on receiving messages.
I'm not establishing the bluetooth connection myself, that is done by methods within the API I'm using

the logcat says:

```
09-20 10:44:31.270: W/bt-btif(883): dm_pm_timer expires
09-20 10:44:31.270: W/bt-btif(883): dm_pm_timer expires 0
09-20 10:44:31.290: W/bt-btif(883): proc dm_pm_timer expires
09-20 10:44:31.310: E/bt-btif(883): bta_dm_pm_btm_status  hci_status=36
```

I read in some other topics, but found no solution for my problem

Here in addition some code of my receiving Thread:

```
class RxThread extends Thread {

    Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            demoRxMsg = new MessageStructure();
            int progress = 0;

            generateLogFileOnSD(logData, logText);

            while (rxChannel.receiveMessage(demoRxMsg) == ReturnCode.SUCCESS) {

                String data = "";
                String format = "";


                rxChannel.receiveMessage(demoRxMsg);

                if (demoRxMsg.frameFormat == API_ADK.STANDARD_FRAME) {
                    format = "SFF";
                } else {
                    format = "EFF";
                }

                for (byte i = 0; i < demoRxMsg.dataLength; i++) {
                    data = data + Integer.toHexString(demoRxMsg.data[i])
                            + " ";

                }


                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                Map keyMap = ResourceUtils.getHashMapResource(DiagnosisActivity.this, R.xml.hashmap1);

                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                Iterator iter = keyMap.entrySet().iterator();

                while(iter.hasNext()) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                    Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                    if (data.contains(mEntry.getKey().toString())) {
                        progress = Integer.parseInt(mEntry.getValue().toString());
                    }
                }

        newLogText = format + "; ID=0x"
                            + Integer.toHexString(demoRxMsg.messageID)
                            + " Data=" + data + "\n";

                    logText = logText + newLogText;

                    writeLogFileOnSD(logData, logText);
                    }
            }
            if (progress != -1) {
                final int newProgress = progress;

                myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60);
                myHandler.post(r);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does anyone have a clue? Found nothing helpful on the internet

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem, turning off and then back on Bluetooth debugging did the trick for me